# Is there a way to view image width and height in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, image-size

Is there a way to view image width and height in Visual Studio Code?
I didn't find any extension nor any setting.

Thanks

Answer (score 49):

No extension is needed. You can find it in the bottom bar of vscode.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer - same as above and I already answered that it wasn't shown in earlier versions

Comment: For me it's not visible anymore.

Answer (score 4):

It was show at the bottom right corner of VSCode.

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't in earlier versions